# Question on tangent and normal for the curve ${x^3 \over a}+{y^3 \over b} =xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, coordinate-systems, curves, tangent-line

Find at what point on the curve $${x^3 \over a}+{y^3 \over b} =xy,$$ the tangent is parallel to one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: And...? What did you try and where did you stuck?

Comment: Not being able to find out the coordinates on the curve from where the tangent passes such that it is parallel to coordinate axes

Comment: Tangent is parallel to one of the axes when either $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: I know this but in the process I am not getting the answer so I want a full solution.

Comment: Do you know how to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$? If you did find it, please edit your question to include that. This will help us to help you.

Comment: Moderators advise you to try some calculations.. We cannot solve your homework problems and provide full solutions !

Comment: For the non-origin tangents you can use the parameterization from $y=tx:$ i.e. $$(x,y)=(t/(t^3/b+1/a),t^2/(t^3/b+1/a))$$ to get the tangent cone for a non-origin point on the curve $$(2a^3b^2t^4-a^2b^3t)(y-t^2/(t^3/b+1/a))+(2a^2b^3t^2-a^3b^2t^5)(x-t/(t^3/b+1/a))=0.$$ To get the horizontal tangent solve $2a^2b^3-a^3b^2t^3=0$ for $t$ to get the tangency at $(\sqrt[3]{2a^2b}/3,\sqrt[3]{4ab^2})$, and to get the vertical tangent solve $2a^3b^2t^3-a^2b^3=0$ for $t,$ to get the tangency at $(\sqrt[3]{4a^2b}/3,\sqrt[3]{2ab^2}/3).$

Comment: No matter what $a\neq 0,b\neq 0,$ the tangent cone is $xy=0,$ so the origin is always singular and the two axes are tangent to the two branches there.

Comment: You got the right answer, This has probably helped me as I was unaware to proceed in this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be improper to provide you with a full solution as you haven't included details about your attempt at the solution. I hope this partial solution helps you as a guide and you can fill out the details on your own.

Take a derivative with respect to x on both sides of the equation:

$\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{x^3}{a}+ \frac{y^3}{b}) = \frac{d}{dx}(xy)$

You can make use of chain rule here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) which gives rise to the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term in the equation. Based on your comments, I do not think you'll have any trouble with this part. I'll omit the denominator part for now.

We get : $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{3x^2}{a}-y}{...}$

For the tangent to be parallel to the x-axis, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ must be $0$. This gives:

$\frac{3x^2}{a}-y = 0 \Longrightarrow y=\frac{3x^2}{a}$

You can now plug this into the original equation of the curve to get $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2a^2b}{27}}$. You can also get the y-value from this.

Can you compute the remaining part by yourself now?

Comment: Yes thanks for your help